# Methods for Targeting Multiple Embedded Hardware Platforms with GNU Make

Tags: makefile, embedded, stm32

How can I ensure that object files compiled for one hardware target will not be used for a different hardware target that needs to be compiled differently?

I am using the GNU ARM Embedded Toolchain while I am learning about embedded development. I already have a couple of development boards (with STM32F0 and STM32F4 processors), and plan to make my own boards in the future. I want to have several iterations of hardware using a common software repository.

Obviously I will have multiple targets in my Makefile, invoking the appropriate defines and compiler flags for each platform, and perhaps a `make all` to build for all platforms at once. As I understand it, `make` is an incremental build system that only re-compiles object code (*.o) files if the source file has been changed, it won't recompile if I have use different defines and options, and the wrong object code will be passed to the linker.

It seems that I could diligently `make clean` when switching between different targets, but that would rely on the human action and could produce bad builds if I forgot, and could not be used for a `make all` that produces multiple binaries for their respective hardware.

**Edit Notes:** Per feedback comments, I have shorted and rearranged to make the question more clear and objective. I'm not asking generically how to use Make, but rather how to prevent, say `mylib.o` being compiled for an STM32F0 and then later being re-used in a build for an STM32F4.

I am curious about alternative tools, and welcome discussion in the comments, but this question is specific to GNU Make.

Comment: I think each target's object files should be stored in a different folder.  Can the target be an input to the make command, and then have target used to determine the path for the object files?

Comment: This question is too broad to give an exhaustive answer. Whole books have been written about `make`. Just a hint: look into the `define`/`enddef`, `eval` and `call` statements. With these, you can generate a whole set of template rules for different platforms from one single, parametrized rule.

Comment: At my old work we decided to force (and enforce) a make clean between switching targets.   There's just to many things that can go wrong otherwise.  @kkrabmbo's solution is good for small or medium sized projects, but for larger projects with third party software/solutions, you have to update and maintain all the third party makefiles.   You have to start asking yourself at what point does this become more work than doing the make cleans.

Comment: Frankly consistency and safety are rather ambitious goals for `make`. The build will occasionally break for _any_ incremental build system and you will get into the habit of forcing a rebuild on phantom bugs, a `make` script just makes this far more likely than most other tools. Certainly a _good_ build system will implicitly track changes to file metadata changing command line arguments, executable tools and the like but ultimately you will be bitten by something silly no matter how hard you try, say an environment variable change. </rant>

Comment: IMO - developing an embedded bare metal device is not an "universal" activity as the target hardware is well known, and all developments boards are handy as you can start work before you get your own hardware.

Comment: @kkrambo I recall reading about setting folders for object files, but hadn't considered that in relation to this problem. It seems like it should work! You should write this as an answer...

Comment: @doynax Sometimes a rant is just a rant wishing for something better, but it sounds like you prefer "most other tools". What other tools would you recommend for embedded development? I'd be most interested in free or low-cost tools that support ARM targets, suitable for open-source projects, and easy to find help/examples for.

Comment: No reason why you cant have one build system (makefile based is fine) that builds from the common sources for all of the targets, each getting their own flash images.  The common files that dont have any if-then-elses (ifdefs) for the target you use a common object built from that source, for the specific ones you build with -D flags  for each and keep the objects separate or for simplicity sake you keep each targets objects spearate and or they even have their own make files called from the top level one.  build systems like this are not new, been around forever, just like

Comment: writing software you can craft the build system however you like.  yes make relies on filenames and their filesystem dates, to work well you want to use actual file names and all their dependencies or overdo it on the dependencies and have a make clean.  if you use too many shortcuts to save on that and dont add the right dependencies then a make clean make will be required and you might as well just write a linear shell script instead of using make files...

Comment: If you prefer not reinventing the wheel, you could look at existing build systems (Linux kernel, U-Boot, Buildroot...). They all target dozens of different hardware platforms. I suggest that you start studying `kbuild`, the Linux build system and use it for your own project.

Comment: You may want to take a look at how contiki os build system works. You specify target platform, and all object files go to directory suffixed by platform's name (i.e. make TARGET=stm32f4disco all). All platform specific code resides in separate dirs etc.

Comment: @mbmcavoy: I won't recommend a specific tool but I would encourage you to shop around for alternatives. What I will say is that most build systems focus on the ease of portability, which is pointless in much of embedded development where you need careful control of one or a few well-known targets and heuristics for automatic configuration mostly get in the way. Consider tools employing general-purpose imperative languages in place of proprietary declarative ones, and tools with extensive support for tracking of implicit dependencies.

Comment: Most importantly though, consider whether your project is sufficiently large to warrant the performance gains of incremental builds. A sequential build executed through your scripting language of choice has the virtue of avoiding any number of headaches, and is both simple and powerful. At the expense of build time but, you know, premature optimizations and all that..

Comment: There&#39;s a very short question in here somewhere.  You would do well to shorten this and get to the point.  The question is very near the end, and many won&#39;t bother reading that far.  To be honest I did not bother reading the pre-amble, so may have missed something, but suggest that if that is the case, it is illustrative of my point.

Comment: So many attempts at an answer in comments!  Why the reticence to post an answer? @old_timer : your suggestion that a common object can be used for files without conditional compilation does not work for builds targeting different architectures requiring different toolchain, or even between say an STM32F1 with no FPU, and STM32F4 with an FPU.  It is simpler and more maintainable to keep all build artefacts separate.

Comment: any question that includes the words "best practices" will get closed with "primarily opinion based", they are not so questions, a comment here or there to move them along then we clean up the mess...

Comment: @old_timer I never said "best". I figured it was likely that more than one technique might work, but did not expect an answer to tell me what's best. In any case, so far there is only one technique identified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the need for a clean build between targets, it is necessary for each target to have separate build directories in order that the target dependencies are independent and specifically generated using the appropriate tool chain and build switches etc.